# How to embed images in email with Mailgun using Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, mailgun

I'm working on a site with the Laravel 4 framework, and I'm attempting to send email batches with the Mailgun bundle by vtalbot.  I need to embed images in the email since we don't have the storage space for the millions of images required.  I know that Mail has a method for this, but since Mailgun is the required mail service, I'm not sure how this can be used (if it even CAN be used).

**EDIT:** Well, turns out Mr. Talbot already thought or this...  He provides functionality for the Mailgun "inline" parameter that allows for inline attachments.  I always find the answer right after asking the question...

Comment: You can use base64-encoded image embedded in the mail, here's some info http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html

Answer (score 1):

I recently created a Laravel 4 package for Mailgun. You might want to check it out.
https://github.com/Bogardo/Mailgun